# How to resize the element using jsPlumb?

Tags: resize, jsplumb

In my application I need to resize the elements. Here I found the perfect example

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/sporritt/HUKMC/9/][1]
```

but its not working in my code.
Even when I used the same code without changing it, it didn't work for me.
Any help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without posting your code it is difficult to debug. Make sure that the object which is resizable is set with below class:

```
$('#resizable').addClass('ui-widget-content');
```